# Cannot update during an existing state transition when updating the state?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux

```
this.state = {
  filterData: [{
    attribute: '-1',
    filter: '-1',
    value: ''
  }],
}


_createFilterUI(dataSourceColumns) {
  if (this.state.dataSourceIndex == -1)
    return <div > Kindly first select Data Source. < /div>
  let dataSource = this.state.datasourcelist,
    dataType = '';
  let filterData = this.state.filterData
  let previousfilters = this.state.d3line.chartDataSo.filterDefintions;
  console.log(filterData.concat(previousfilters));


  this.setState({
    filterData: filterData.concat(previousfilters)
  })


  return this.state.filterData && this.state.filterData.map((el, i) => {

    if (el.attribute != -1) {
      dataType = dataSource[this.state.dataSourceIndex].columnDescription[el.attribute].JAVA_DATA_TYPE;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        { some content }
      </div>)
    )
  })
}
```

[image]

`filterData` is part of my state. 
When I'm trying to update the filterData state with `filterData.concat(previousfilters)`

It is not getting updated and I am getting `Cannot update during an existing state transition` error after keeping `setState`

Please, anyone, guide me how to update the `filterdata` state and explain what I'm doing wrong.

I'm unable to update the state properly after I console it.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two issues here. I cannot fully tell because there is not enough code shown, but I'm going to guess that you are calling `_createFilterUI` from the `render` method or `componentWillUpdate`. You are allowed to call other methods from these methods, but you are not allowed to call `setState` during them.

Also, `setState` [does not automatically update the component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) so in your snippet above, you cannot rely on having the new state immediately after you call `setState`. You will have to do the rest of your function in the callback you can supply `setState` or in another point in the lifecycle.

Comment: Yes exactly, I am calling _createFilterUI function from render.